# Create/Align Columns in CSS without using tables

Tags: html, css

I have a unique design question. Basically I'm writing a chat script and would like to make the layout more uniform. Is it possible to have a unique set of columns per chat line without creating a new table for each line? For instance this is the design I am ideally looking for.

```
    [TimeStamp] Me: I am writing a long message and this text will be
                    wrapped to the next line. See how the message text
                    is aligned perfectly when wrapped?
    [TimeStamp] Them: When they write a message that requires wrapping
                      it aligns perfectly for them.
    [TimeStamp] OtherPeople: I think this makes the concept clear if it
                             needs wrapping it aligns for each "poster"
```

If I create 1 table for all the messages it may make certain columns longer than they should be. I know creating a new table for each new post could accomplish this, just wondering if there is a more "Web 2.0" CSS way of doing this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a table use divs for the poster name and the text.

so:

```
<div id="everything"><div id="everythingInside">
<div id="timestamp">[timestamp]</div>
<div id="poster">TheCoolGuy</div>
<div id="comment">I"m cooler than you!</div>
</div>
</div>
```

then use css to display it as a table:

```
#everything { display: table; }
#everythingInside { display: table-row; }
#timestamp, #poster, #comment { display: table-cell; }
```

Of course there are other ways using divs and further CSS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `code`, `pre`, (and `var`, `span`, `div`) and friends. `pre` and `code` gives you whitespace-sensitive, fixed-width text, so the columns work just like above (in fact, you could just view source or inspect element). StackOverflow seems to use [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to do highlighting if you need that.

Comment: doesn't `code` and `pre` only align if there are spaces in the text to align them though?

Comment: Oh I see, I just assumed your text was already wrapped and spaced, you just didn't know how to use it outside a table. Yes, the text needs spaces. It might be easier to format the text on the client with JavaScript or the server with your favorite language before presenting it.